How to change WC query_vars from within a custom filter form (shortcode in sidebar)?
I have built a simple form that I put into a sidebar via a shortcode. I needed to do this because our tags are "key:value" pairs, so I need my filter to explode the pairs and group the values by the keys in an accordion-style menu. I then need to reassemble the tag for the submit.
The code for that is below (I have not included the css and js for the accordion functionality - it works, so hopefully it's not needed here). This code works IF I only want to filter by a single product_tag. However, I am trying to change it to work for selecting multiple product_tags.
This code submits the query as an argument in the url (i.e. "shop?product_tag=Tag"). I had thought to simply look at the query_vars and pre-check the product_tag that is already checked. Then, when I check a second tag, two product_tag arguments would be sent via the url. However, that doesn't work because only the last product_tag url gets picked up by query_vars. So, if I use "shop?product_tag=Tag1&product_tag=Tag2" in the url, only Tag2 appears in the query_vars until product_tag.
So there must be another way to modify the query_vars from my form so I can select multiple checkboxes. But I can't figure out how. Anyone here know the magic hook/javascript for my "onchange"?
function my_custom_tag_filter()
{
    global $wp_query;

    $return = '';

    $query_vars = $wp_query->query_vars;

    $tags = get_terms('product_tag');
    $tagsbycategory = array();
    if (!empty($tags) && !is_wp_error($tags)) {
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $tagcategorypair = explode(":", $tag->name);
            if (count($tagcategorypair) != 2) continue;
            if (!array_key_exists($tagcategorypair[0], $tagsbycategory)) {
                $tagsbycategory[$tagcategorypair[0]] = array();
            }
            $tagsbycategory[$tagcategorypair[0]][] = $tagcategorypair[1];
        }
    }

    $return .= '
        <form id="myfilter">
    ';

    $keys = array_keys($tagsbycategory);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $return .= '
            <button type="button" class="collapsiblefilter">' . $key . '</button>
            <div class="filtercontent">
        ';

        $values = $tagsbycategory[$key];
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $argvalue = str_replace(' ', '-', $value);
            $friendlyvalue = str_replace('/','',str_replace(' ', '', $value));
            $id = $key . '-' . $friendlyvalue . '-check';

            $return .= '
                    <div class="filtercheckdiv">
                        <label for="' . $id . '"><input class="ajax-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="' . $key . ':' . $argvalue . '" id="' . $id . '" name="product_tag" onChange="this.form.submit()" />&nbsp;' . $value . '</label>
                    </div>
            ';
        }

        $return .= '
            </div>
        ';
    }
    if ($query_vars != null) {
        if (array_key_exists("s", $query_vars)) {
            $return .= '<input type="hidden" id="s" value="' . $query_vars["s"] . '">';
        }
        if (array_key_exists("orderby", $query_vars)) {
            $return .= '<input type="hidden" id="sorderby value="' . $query_vars["orderby"] . '">';
        }
        if (array_key_exists("order", $query_vars)) {
            $return .= '<input type="hidden" id="order" value="' . $query_vars["order"] . '">';
        }
    }

    $return .= '
        <div class="small"><a href="#" class="deselect" onChange="this.form.submit()">Clear Filter</a>
        </form>
    ';
  
    return $return;
}
add_shortcode('my_custom_filter', 'my_custom_tag_filter');


I figured it out. For anyone who has a similar problem, I did a few things:

Create a custom query_var variable. (This may not be necessary, but it helped me keep things straight.)

function add_query_vars_filter($query_vars)
{
    $query_vars[] = "my_filters";
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter');


Change the name attribute of the input elements in the my_custom_tag_filter function that renders the form to the new query_var as an array.

<input class="..." type="checkbox" value="..." id="..." name="my_filters[]" onChange="this.form.submit()"/>


Use the pre_get_posts hook to change the query to use the custom query_var:

function map_my_filter($query) {
    if (is_admin() || ($query->get('post_type')!='product')) return;

    $my_filters = $query->get('my_filters') ?: array();

    if (count($my_filters) == 0) return;

    $product_tags_by_category = array();
    foreach ($my_filters as $tag) {
        $keyvalue = explode(':', $tag);
        if (count($keyvalue) == 2) {
            if (!array_key_exists($keyvalue[0], $product_tags_by_category))
                $product_tags_by_category[$keyvalue[0]] = array();
            $product_tags_by_category[$keyvalue[0]][] = $tag;
        }
    }

    $new_tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND', );
    foreach (array_keys($product_tags_by_category) as $key) {
        $new_tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'terms' => $product_tags_by_category[$key],
            'field' => 'slug',
        );
    }

    $tax_query = $query->get('tax_query') ?: array();
    $tax_query[] = $new_tax_query;

    $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'map_my_filter', 1);


Fix dumb errors and prevent certain problematic UI behaviors not related to my problem but worth sharing if someone is following along.

Avoid a single search result from redirecting to the product screen. This means a filter that narrows down to one will still land on an archive page that shows the filter UI.
function remove_search_redirect()
{
    return false;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_redirect_single_search_result', 'remove_search_redirect', 10);

Set the action on the form to the base URL of the shop so that, if the user filters when on page 2+ of a previous search query/all products, and the filter results in fewer products such that there is no longer a page 2+, the filter won't return "no products" due to the pagination URL format of /shop/page/2/?args=....
<form id="fabrixfilter" action="/shop/">

Set the name attribute of the hidden inputs, NOT the id attribute. Otherwise, existing search terms and ordering settings will not be preserved when filtering. Also, add a hidden input element for product_type just in case.
 $return .= '<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">';
 if ($query_vars != null) {
     if (array_key_exists("s", $query_vars)) {
         if (trim($query_vars["s"])!='') $return .= '<input type="hidden" name="s" value="' . $query_vars["s"] . '">';
     }
     if (array_key_exists("orderby", $query_vars)) {
         $return .= '<input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="' . $query_vars["orderby"] . '">';
     }
     if (array_key_exists("order", $query_vars)) {
         $return .= '<input type="hidden" name="order" value="' . $query_vars["order"] . '">';
     }
 }

I'm pretty sure that's everything I did to get the filters working with custom key/value pair tags. If I realize I left something out, I will come back and edit this solution. I hope this helps someone else!
